# I've got scammed and the scammer sent the crypto to a smart contract. Why?

Tags: transactions

A month ago I was scammed, and although I know that I will not be able to recover the crypto, I have some doubts.
I've been following the scammer's moves across different accounts, hoping he'd make the mistake of sending them to an exchange, but got stuck here:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x36adb0c2bba47b57ac9d050ac83ffbc16b678edc
As you can see, that account received about $660k from a ledger reported account, and then I lost track. What happened to crypto? Where have he sent them?
I'm just curious, I can't follow the movements anymore?

From what I see it has interacted with a contract, which until recently I didn't even know what they were for. Can someone explain to me a little more about what could have happened?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: from what i see he could have been swapped them to DAI and transferred them to the Binance Smart Chain using the (AnySwap Bridge). (but maybe sorry not i'm not good enough with bridges and swaps) sorry for your lost.

Comment: Thanks @MajdTL, I can follow him now in bscscan.

Answer (score 0):

I was also hacked and confirmed that it was deposited into this wallet through a scan.
What I found out is that you can swap in dollars, OlympusDAO,
It was confirmed that he withdrew from Pancake Swap.
Again 0x36ADB0C2BBa47b57ac9D050aC83ffBc16B678EDc
If I withdraw money from this wallet, I will track it down again.

Comment: Did you get scammed by the same guy? Or just a similar case? Anyway thanks, Im also up to date in his movements.